# set the year before this year - Database - php

Tags: php, mysqli

working on since even be able to find the year that has been there before. that is, we are in 2015 so it must just take all those who have the previous year. However, it does not grasp the year we are in right moment.

Only just like to

```
printf("<br>i år 2013 var der %d. brænde", $mebe->statistik("2013"));
```

It just took years even then as soon as I get to 2014 it was at 2013, but I get to 2015 so I had both 2013 and 2014 without I just had to add them to the code so that somehow did not tackle the year you were in.

the roof like this from the database with the time and date:

2013-05-01 11:13:48

it must be such that it only checks the year.

```
function statistik($year=""){       
    $year=($year !="")? $year : date("Y");
    $row_cnt=0;
    if ($result = $this->mysqli->query("SELECT melding, tidspunkt FROM alarm WHERE YEAR(tidspunkt)=$year")) {
        $row_cnt = $result->num_rows;       
        /* close result set */
        $result->close();
    }   
    return $row_cnt;    
}
```

It will even find out the year so the few years before this year.

Comment: I take it English isn't your first language, and that's just fine, but your question isn't quite clear enough to understand what you want.

Comment: You can try `echo date("Y", strtotime('last year'));` or `echo date("Y", strtotime('next year'));` as the case may be

Comment: Sorry but I'm dyslexic and poor english: (

Answer (score 1):

There are many ways to accomplish this. For example:

```
$thisYear = date('Y', time());
$previousYear = $thisYear - 1;
```

Answer (score 0):

If I understood your question correctly, try replacing this line in your function

```
$year=($year !="")? $year-1 : date("Y", strtotime('-1 year'));
```

What this does is check if year is passed to the function. If it indeed is, it's reduced by 1 and if not then the current year is taken and then reduced by 1.

Comment: I'm not against downvoting, but at least have to courtesy to specify the reason for the downvote.

Comment: it does not, it appears, type 0 on both things and it will not be, indicating the year here:

`
$year=($year !="")? $year-1 : date("Y", strtotime('-1 year'));
  $row_cnt=0;
  if ($result = $this->mysqli->query("SELECT melding, tidspunkt FROM alarm WHERE YEAR(tidspunkt)=$year")) {
   $row_cnt = $result->num_rows;  
   /* close result set */
   $result->close();
  } 
  return $row_cnt;

printf("<br>i år 2013 var der %d. brænde", $mebe->statistik("2013") );
  printf("<br>i dette år har der været %d. brænde", $mebe->statistik());



`